# How to Round a decimal number by its second decimal place PHP

Tags: php, numbers, rounding

How to Round a  decimal number by its second decimal place PHP

if the number is 1.18 it need to round to 1.20

How can i achieve this using php?

Thank you

Comment: Did you try using the `round()` function?

Comment: `echo round(1.95583, 2);  // 1.96` Try this. For More: http://php.net/round

Comment: yes.but not working. i want 1.95 to 2.00
or 1.88 to 1.90 like that .
you get what i am talking about?

Comment: It's called: rounding to one decimal place, as you expect the result to have at most one number after the decimal point. You should try `round(1.18,1)` to get `1.2`. To get `1.20`, it's a matter of formatting the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds a bit strange, but this will accomplish what you're after:

```
echo number_format(round(1.18, 1), 2);
```

First, it will round the number to a single decimal place making it `1.2`, then it will format that to ensure there are 2 decimal places again making it `1.20`

Comment: THANK YOU .It worked perfeclty. Thank you all

Answer (score 2):

This is specific to your example and will output 1.2

```
echo round(1.18, 1);
```

Added the following to get your two digits.

```
<?php 
    $inputNum = 1.18;
    $num = round($inputNum, 1);
    printf ("%0.2f", $num);
?>
```

Comment: i looked at it, but i want 1.95 to 2.00 or 1.88 to 1.90 like that . you get what i am talking about?

Comment: I think he has 1.96 and round(1.96, 2); won't do anything or from the question round(1.18, 2); never be 1.20

Comment: @MukulJayaprakash Did my response work for you?

Comment: yes. 
but i used number_format instead of printf
thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this page.
http://php.net/round

What does it do?
Simply rounds a float(which is the one you need). :)

Comment: this look likes it .let me try it.what do you think ?
round( 1.55, 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN);